# Passing root object into component in ractive

Tags: ractivejs

Is this a bug or have I missunderstood something.

The {{.}} notation when passing data to a component only works inside a loop.

So

```
<div>
   <myComponenet obj={{.}} />
</div
```

Does not work, but

```
{{#SomeList}}
<div>
   <myComponenet obj={{.}} />
</div
{{/s}}
```

Works fine..

How to pass the "root" object into the component?

Comment: It's a bug. Please file issue on https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues

Comment: @martypdx Wasn't this fixed in edge? ...this bug sounds familiar

Comment: @arnaud I tried the example with edge in jsfiddle and it failed.

Comment: @martypdx: Works for me on edge, see http://jsfiddle.net/qy6gcfg3/7/ ...btw, related to https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1548

Comment: huh, must have goofed something. Glad to be wrong about it. :D